# A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in Microsoft.Phone.Data.Internal.ni.dll

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-phone-7

I have added a new column to my database table. When I have added this new columnm, the first chance exception start appearing. When I debugged it, it stated the code line
**MLongListSelector.ItemsSource = c.ToDoList.ToList();** 
is the next statement to execute that causes the problem. What have I done wrong there?

```
using (DatabaseContext c = new DatabaseContext(DatabaseContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            c.CreateIfNotExists();
            c.LogDebug = true;
            //output todolist data from database
            MLongListSelector.ItemsSource = c.ToDoList.ToList();
        }
```

stack trace of that line:

```
    ex.StackTrace   "   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.CompileQueryPlan()\r\n   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, String method, ResultSetOptions options)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult, Boolean isCompiledQuery)\r\n   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Boolean isCompiledQuery)\r\n   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query)\r\n   at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Data.Linq.Table`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEntity>.GetEnumerator()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at PhoneApp.MainPage.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)"
```

e.message:

```
    ex.Message  "The column name is not valid. [ Node name (if any) = t0,Column name = Col ]"   string
```

Get and Set:

```
public partial class ToDoList : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _Id;

    private string _Title;

    private string _Description;

    private string _Col;

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnLoaded();
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
partial void OnCreated();
partial void OnIdChanging(int value);
partial void OnIdChanged();
partial void OnTitleChanging(string value);
partial void OnTitleChanged();
partial void OnDescriptionChanging(string value);
partial void OnDescriptionChanged();
partial void OnColChanging(string value);
partial void OnColChanged();
#endregion

    public ToDoList()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Id", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Id != value))
            {
                this.OnIdChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Id = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Id");
                this.OnIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Title", DbType="NVarChar(100) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Title;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Title != value))
            {
                this.OnTitleChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Title = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Title");
                this.OnTitleChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Description", DbType="NVarChar(100)")]
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Description;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Description != value))
            {
                this.OnDescriptionChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Description = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Description");
                this.OnDescriptionChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Col", DbType="NVarChar(25)")]
    public string Col
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Col;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Col != value))
            {
                this.OnColChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Col = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Col");
                this.OnColChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the exception stack trace and message. Likewise for the inner exception if it's not null.

Comment: Im sorry but im new. I dont get what does Post the exception stack trace and message means here

Comment: run in debug mode, then in exception message pop up, click "view detail"

Comment: > PhoneApp.DLL!PhoneApp.MainPage.OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) Line 43 C#
 this is what i get. do you mean this?

Comment: Added the stacktrace on my post

Comment: Getting closer, what is in "e.Message"? does the resource here help? http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/239820-linq-to-sql-and-sqlce-wth/

Comment: Hi, I took a look at that post. Its more towards my get and set primary key. I have posted mine. Only my ID is the primary key here.

Comment: e.message is posted too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your solution and i don't see why it should not work. Do you have the ToDoList marked with a "Table attribute"? i.e.

```
[Table]
public partial class ToDoList : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
```

Also, it might be worth you dropping the database and recreating it. Follow the code sample below and try to go from there. if this does not work then feel free to attach a simple project that replicates the issue.

**Xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <ListBox x:Name="lstToDos">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"></TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

**Code behind**

```
public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        using (DatabaseContext c = new DatabaseContext(DatabaseContext.ConnectionString))
        {
            c.CreateIfNotExists(); 

            //Add new records for debug sake: 
            var dateNow = DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay.ToString();
            var newToDo = new ToDoList { Col = "Col" + dateNow, Description = "Some description" + dateNow, Title = "Some title" + dateNow };

            c.ToDoLists.InsertOnSubmit(newToDo);
            c.SubmitChanges();

            lstToDos.ItemsSource = c.ToDoLists.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

**Data context file**

```
public class DatabaseContext : DataContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(string connectionString)
    : base(connectionString)
    {

    }


    public Table<ToDoList> ToDoLists
    {
        get
        {
            return this.GetTable<ToDoList>();
        }
    }

    public void CreateIfNotExists()
    {
        if (!this.DatabaseExists())
        {
            this.CreateDatabase();
        }
    }

    public const string ConnectionString = @"isostore:/MyDatabases.sdf";
}
```

**ToDO entity**

```
 [Table]
public partial class ToDoList : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _Id;

    private string _Title;

    private string _Description;

    private string _Col;

    #region Extensibility Method Definitions
    partial void OnLoaded();
    partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
    partial void OnCreated();
    partial void OnIdChanging(int value);
    partial void OnIdChanged();
    partial void OnTitleChanging(string value);
    partial void OnTitleChanged();
    partial void OnDescriptionChanging(string value);
    partial void OnDescriptionChanged();
    partial void OnColChanging(string value);
    partial void OnColChanged();
    #endregion

    public ToDoList()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage = "_Id", AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType = "Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Id != value))
            {
                this.OnIdChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Id = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Id");
                this.OnIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage = "_Title", DbType = "NVarChar(100) NOT NULL", CanBeNull = false)]
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Title;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Title != value))
            {
                this.OnTitleChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Title = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Title");
                this.OnTitleChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage = "_Description", DbType = "NVarChar(100)")]
    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Description;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Description != value))
            {
                this.OnDescriptionChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Description = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Description");
                this.OnDescriptionChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage = "_Col", DbType = "NVarChar(25)")]
    public string Col
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Col;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Col != value))
            {
                this.OnColChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Col = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Col");
                this.OnColChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangingEventHandler PropertyChanging;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanging()
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanging != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanging(this, emptyChangingEventArgs);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void SendPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        if ((this.PropertyChanged != null))
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @FunksMaName, thanks for your time in doing the cod. The line c.CreateIfNotExists();  in the code behind had a small bugged where i solved it with your code but replacing that with if (!c.DatabaseExists())
                {
                    c.CreateDatabase();
                }

Comment: Thanks alot! Now after a whole day of testing im able to relax! Thanks once again